# big.Int not equal to one received after big.setBytes(bigint.Bytes())

Tags: go, bigint

I want to convert a big int to bytes and the bytes back to big int and then compare the two values. I am doing it using similar code as below:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "math/big"

func main() {
    input := "37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250"
    a := big.NewInt(0)
    a.SetString(input, 10)
    fmt.Println("number =", a)

    z := a.Bytes()
    b := big.NewInt(0)
    b.SetBytes(z)

    fmt.Println("number =", b)

    if a!=b{
        fmt.Println("foo")
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
number = 37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250
number = 37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250
foo
```

This is strange, the numbers look equal. The code inside if loop should not be executed. 
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are comparing the [pointers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types) to the `big.Int` values, and not the internal `big.Int` values. Comparing `big.Int` values must be done using the [`Int.Cmp` method](https://godoc.org/math/big#Int.Cmp):

> ```
> func (x *Int) Cmp(y *Int) (r int)
> ```
>
> Cmp compares x and y and returns:
>
> ```
> -1 if x <  y
> 0 if x == y
> +1 if x >  y
> ```

```
if a.Cmp(b) != 0 {
    fmt.Println("foo")
}
```